# Django unrecognized token: "@" while query

Tags: django, search, django-queryset, operationalerror

I simply want to implement a search view into my Django app. But when i try to search something on my App i get the following error:

```
'unrecognized token: "@"'
```

In the end i want that my Query is a combination of category and searchword. So that the user can filter specific categories (Just like Amazon.com searchfield) e.g.: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?category=1&q=hallo`

**base.html**

```
...
   <div class="globalsearch">
            <form id="searchform" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <label for="{{ categorysearch_form.category.id_for_label }}">In category: </label> {{ categorysearch_form.category }}
                <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
                <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

...
```

categorysearch_form is a dropdown selector that gets his ID from the Database.

**views.py**

```
...
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
from django.views.generic import ListView


class globalsearch(ListView):
    """
    Display a Post List page filtered by the search query.
    """
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Post.objects.all()

        keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query = SearchQuery(keywords)
            title_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A')
            content_vector = SearchVector('content', weight='B')
            tag_vector = SearchVector('tag', weight='C')
            vectors = title_vector + content_vector + tag_vector
            qs = qs.annotate(search=vectors).filter(search=query)
            qs = qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).order_by('-rank')

        return qs

...
```

**urls.py**

```
...

url(r'^search/$', views.globalsearch.as_view(), name='search'),

...
```

**Search.html** results are getting displayd here:

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**Post Model**

```
...
#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    postattachment = fields.FileField(upload_to='postattachment/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True ,null=True)
    postcover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='postcover/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 200, 'max_height': 200}))
    ])
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
...
```

i guess im simply missing something
at that point...
I already read that this issue comes from local SQL database aka. SQLite, could that be true?
Smb. has a solution?
Thanks

Comment: I think, changing the DB to `postgres` will solve the issue. Did you tried?

Comment: Why are you trying to use postgres functions in sqlite in the first place?

Comment: I'm no to Django, i just found this issue on another thread. I did not try postgres till now but i will in the next days. I found this code example somewhere on the web but i can remember that smb. has written something about Postgres. Anyways, thanks for the feedback :) Love this community

Comment: Can i also use MySQL or is this PostGres only related query statement?

Comment: I now have setup a PostGres DB on my machine (nice thing), now i don't get back any error, now i get back nothing... Yeah...
I set a breakpoint at "return qs" in debug mode (Pycharm) in my views.py. please see results here: https://pastebin.com/zJ3TVQd1
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering with a friend i found a solution, the Django Documentation according to vector searching is really not that good...

**views.py**

```
class globalsearch(ListView):
    """
    Display a Post List page filtered by the search query.
    """
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    template_name = 'quickblog/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query = SearchQuery(keywords)
            title_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A')
            content_vector = SearchVector('content', weight='B')
            tag_vector = SearchVector('tag', weight='C')
            vectors = title_vector + content_vector + tag_vector
            qs = Post.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).filter(rank__gte=0.1).order_by('-rank')
            return qs
```

**models.py**

```
#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    postattachment = fields.FileField(upload_to='postattachment/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True ,null=True)
    postcover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='postcover/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 200, 'max_height': 200}))
    ])
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}


{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^search/$', views.globalsearch.as_view(), name='search'),
```

Hope that i was able to help the next one with that Post :D